# convergence of translation operators in Sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

The Rellich-Kondrachov theorem says that the inclusion of $W^{1,p}(U)$ in $L^q(U)$ is a compact operator for $q < dp/(d-p)$, where U is a bounded open subset of $d$ dimensional Euclidean space with $C^1$ boundary. In light of the Riesz-Kolmogorov theorem this implies that if $T_a$ is the translation operator by some vector $a$, then we should be able to find a function $\alpha$ such that for each $f \in W^{1,p}(U)$,

$$ \| T_a f - f \|_{L^q} \leq \alpha(a) \| f \|_{W^{1,p}}, $$

where $\alpha(a)$ converges to zero as $a \to 0$. What methods enable us to prove this directly?

Comment: I just came back to this, and I just realised, there can't be translation in $L^p$ on a bounded set, as translating pushes you out of the set!

Comment: You can treat the functions as being zero outside of the set, and then integrating solely on the set U. There was some mild technicalities while going through the argument rigorously but everything seemed to work out.

Comment: i think usually you consider the function in a smaller set instead. Extending by zero may take you out of the sobolev space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that **if $p=q$**, this follows easily from taking a derivative: $$(T_af-f)(x)=\int_0^a{(\nabla u)(x+y)\,dy}$$  By [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality), we can move the $p$-norm inside the integral, so that $$\|T_af-f\|_p\leq\int_0^a{\|T_y\nabla u\|_p\,dy}$$  Since $T_y$ is norm-preserving, we are integrating a constant.  Thus $$\|T_af-f\|_p\leq a\|\nabla u\|_p$$

**For the general case,** one can use the [Sobolev inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality), although this may not be as elementary as you like: $$\|T_af-f\|_{L^q}\leq C\|T_af-f\|_{W^p}\leq2C\|f\|_{W^p}$$ by triangle inequality.

Comment: This seems like the right kind of approach, but we need to switch the L^p norm on the left with an L^q norm.

Comment: Ooh, totally missed that!

Comment: This is closer, but we want to replace the 2 with a constant which goes to zero as a goes to zero. I suspect for this hypothesis you need to use the hypothesis that q is less than $dp/(d-p)$ - right now your argument only needs that q is less than or equal to $dp/(d-p)$.

Comment: @JacobDenson indeed, you can use Lebesgue interpolation between $L^{p*}$ and $L^p$ to finish. This gives bounds for all $q\in[p,p*]$ but convergence to zero only for $q<p*$

Comment: Of course - I should have seen that from the inequalities above my bad :).

Comment: @JacobDenson no problem :) (I'm not the other jacob but couldnt resist commenting)